# Atualizar um Repeater após inserir uma nova linha na Tabela?

Tags: ajax, asp.net, webforms, table

Bom dia, galera!

Tenho uma tabela que é populada com um Repeater. Essa tabela tem um filtro, que está programado todo via javascript de um Layout pronto. Após adicionar um novo valor na tabela e utilizar o filtro dela, aparece apenas os valores iniciais, quando a tabela foi carregada.

Estrutura da tabela:

```
<div id="divtabela" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 table-responsive table-red filter-right">
              <table id="tabelaprodutos" class="table table-striped table-hover table-dynamic">
               <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>Descrição</th>
                     <th>Item</th>
                   </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptProdutos">
                         <ItemTemplate>
                              <tr>
                                 <td style='vertical-align: middle;'><%# rptPostNome(Container) %></td>
                                 <td style='vertical-align: middle;width:25%'><%# rptPostAtivo(Container) %></td>  
                             </tr>
                         </ItemTemplate>
                   </asp:Repeater>
                 </tbody>
              </table>
    </div>
```

Eu adiciono um valor a essa tabela via Ajax(Adiciono também no banco, na mesma requisição):

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "novoDispositivo.aspx/testeajax",
         data: '{produto: ' + JSON.stringify(produto) + '}',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (response) {

                        if (response.d != "") {

                        var quebra = response.d.split('~~');

                        $("#tabelaprodutos")
                        .prepend(
                            "<tr role='row'><td style='vertical-align: middle;'>"
                              + quebra[0] +
                            "</td><td style='vertical-align: middle;'>"
                              + quebra[1] +
                            "</td><td style='text-align:right; padding-right:50px'>"  
                              + quebra[2] +
                            "</td></tr>" 
                         );
```

Até aqui tudo funciona perfeitamente, adiciona no banco e popula a tabela.

Acontece que quando eu vou utilizar o Filtro, ele some com os novos valores adicionados na tabela. E só volta a aparecer quando eu dou um postback, atualizo a página ou afins.

Há alguma forma de eu atualizar os dados do meu Repeater sem dar o postback? De forma que, quando eu utilizar o filtro ele reconheça esses novos valores adicionados?

Muito obrigado desde já!

Comment: Conhece ou já tentou usar um UpdatePanel? Talvez sirva http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers